# SQL check if the value is more than 4 then update the other column stop the updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I I have one tables updating two columns if the second column the update more or equal to 4 set the other column to 0

Tried case statement .... but still not working please help!

```
update [dbo].[QueuedSms_TEST]
    set issent = 0,pendingstatusid = pendingstatusid + 1
    where sendresponse is null

while (select pendingstatusid from [dbo].[QueuedSms_TEST]) > 3
    update [dbo].[QueuedSms_TEST]
    set issent = -1
```

Comment: Can you define "not working"? What is that loop trying to do? It looks like an endless loop because you are never changing the loop condition inside the loop. You need to provide us a lot more information here.

Comment: @SeanLange I dont know how but I understand what he want. He want autonumeric for pendingstatus and if is >=4 set `issent = -1`

Answer (score 0):

First you create a temporal query to get a row_number, and then update that with the required rules.

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/FQQZ1509)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pendingstatusid) as rn
    FROM QueuedSms_TEST
)    
UPDATE cte
SET pendingstatusid = rn,
    issent = CASE WHEN rn > 3 
                  THEN -1
                  ELSE 0
             END;
```